# Using URL vs Filepath to include css?

Tags: php, css, url, path

Which one is better ?
Using URL to include css ?
`<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo BASE_URL; ?>/css/style.css">`

Or, using filesystem ?
`<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo BASE_PATH; ?>/css/style.css">`

`BASE_URL` containes the base url of the app, and `BASE_PATH` contains the file path to the base of the app.

Comment: If BASE_PATH is the path to the base directory of the app on the filesystem this will not work because the browser will look for something like `http://example.com/var/www/myapplication`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume BASE_URL has value like http://www.example.com/whatver and BASE_PATH is like /whatever.

Then these values are equal. One little plus for BASE_PATH - if you change scheme from http to https, you don't need to check if BASE_URL has new https scheme.